# Angular doesn't recognize the static path of an image from css3

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have tried to assign an image to a div through css style, the problem is that I tried to reach the path of the static file but it is not possible to recognize the route that I indicated... the css code is as follows:

```css
.home-inner {
  background-image: url(./assets/img/intro.jpg)
}
```

This is an image of the project in which the path of the assets folder appears and where the image is stored..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxFoJ.png)

I have been trying in many ways to add the image with the background-image but I am not sure why it does not recognize the path of that image

Comment: Looks like your filepath is incorrect, try: assuming your in navbar.component,ts
../assets/img/intro.jpg

Comment: I already tried to put the route like this and he claims me for the **".."**

Comment: have you tried wrapping your path in '' so it would be: '../assets/img/intro.jpg'

Comment: I found the correct path was: **"../../../assets/img/intro.jpg"**, but it still doesn't show the image as background

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.home-inner {
  background-image: url(assets/img/intro.jpg);
}
```

Comment: When you remove the **"/"** you claim that you do not own it before the route assets/img/intro.jpg